# ruby script cron not working

Tags: ruby, cron, ubuntu-14.04

[image]I have a ruby script in ~/scri.rb

```
File.open('~/newfile.txt', 'a+') do |f|
  f << "hi..\n"
end
```

I have a cron tab like this

```
* * * * * bash -lc 'ruby ~/scri.rb' >> /var/log/syslog
```

When I check the logs in /var/log/syslog I see entries like this

```
Sep  8 14:49:01 user1acer CRON[26063]: (user1) CMD (bash -lc 'ruby ~/scri.rb' >> /var/log/syslog)
Sep  8 14:50:01 user1acer CRON[27502]: (user1) CMD (bash -lc 'ruby ~/scri.rb' >> /var/log/syslog)
Sep  8 14:51:01 user1acer CRON[29006]: (user1) CMD (bash -lc 'ruby ~/scri.rb' >> /var/log/syslog)
Sep  8 14:52:01 user1acer CRON[30425]: (user1) CMD (bash -lc 'ruby ~/scri.rb' >> /var/log/syslog)
Sep  8 14:53:01 user1acer CRON[31846]: (user1) CMD (bash -lc 'ruby ~/scri.rb' >> /var/log/syslog)
```

But when I check the newfile.txt file I see nothing in there.

Am I missing something here ?

Comment: You need to use full paths in cron. So instead of `~/newfile.txt`, write `/home/your_user/newfile.txt` so that cron knows where to locate the file. In fact, you probably have the file in `/`, which is root's home dir.

Comment: newfile.txt is in home directory.

Comment: OK, I am not familiar with Ruby. So if you want to open that file to append content, you need to tell cron about its full path. Try it out with `/home/...` instead of `~`, as said before.

Comment: Usually, root's home directory is `/root`, not `/`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has nothing to do with cron, actually. `~` is a feature of the shell, Ruby doesn't know what it is. Only *some* methods in Ruby deal with `~`, e.g. `File::expand_path`. So, Ruby is literally trying to open a file named `newfile.txt` in directory named `~` in the current working directory. Try it out yourself: create an empty directory named `~` in your home directory, and sure enough, after 1 minute, you should find a new file named `newfile.txt` with the content `hi..` in there.

There are a couple of ways to fix this, I will leave it up to you which one to use:

```
File.open(File.expand_path('~/newfile.txt'), 'a') do |f| end
File.open(File.join(Dir.home, 'newfile.txt'), 'a') do |f| end
```

[Note: if you only want to append to the end of the file, not move around or read, `a` is enough, you don't need `a+`.]

See the documentation for [`File::expand_path`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/File.html#method-c-expand_path) (**bold** emphasis mine):

> ## `expand_path(file_name [, dir_string] )` → `abs_file_name`
>
> Converts a pathname to an absolute pathname. Relative paths are referenced from the current working directory of the process unless `dir_string` is given, in which case it will be used as the starting point. **The given pathname may start with a “*~*”, which expands to the process owner’s home directory** (the environment variable `HOME` must be set correctly). “*~user*” expands to the named user’s home directory.

Comment: the key here is that the environment variable HOME is not set when running a script through cron.

Comment: Ah. I didn't even think to investigate that far, because the OP's script was already broken even *without* involving cron at all. Is that also true when running a login shell from cron? I thought it was the login shell's job to set `$HOME`, not cron's.

Comment: In fact I was wrong, just checked it doing `* * * * * echo "$HOME" > /tmp/myhome`. What is true is that `env` contains way less values than a normal session. For sure, `~` is not understood by cron, so a valid path has to be given.

Comment: Well, the `~` is quoted, so it isn't interpreted by cron but by bash. I think. It may actually be quoted "too much" so it isn't interpreted at all. Oh, how I love dealing with multiple levels of string interpretation and quoting. Not.